# Ajax call to Restful Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I am having an issue trying to recieve a string back from my Restful Web service. 
My ajax code looks like this

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showName(str)
        {   
          if (str=="")
          {
            document.getElementById("playerInfo").innerHTML="Player information will be listed here.";
            return;
          }

    var n =  "path/to/jboss"+str;
         document.getElementById("testURL").innerHTML=n;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: n,
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(resp){
             document.getElementById("playerInfo").innerHTML=resp;
        },
        error:function(e){
            document.getElementById("playerInfo").innerHTML="Error: " + e;
        }
    });
    }

        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action=""> 
        <select name="id" onchange="showName(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select an id number:</option>
            <option value="51902">51902</option>
            <option value="51907">51907</option>
            <option value="51916">51916</option>
        </select>
    </form>
  <div id="testURL"></div>
    <div id="playerInfo">Player information will be listed here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The str that is being passes through is the parameter for my application on that page. It is suppose to return an HTML String but it always goes to error and never to success. Can anyone diagnose this issue for me?

Comment: What error does it give you? `console.log(arguments)` within `error:fn`

Comment: Can you view the AJAX response in Firebug? (Open Firebug, click Net and the XHR inspect tab.)

Comment: Maybe a Same Origin Problem here. Is the domain where you run this the same with the one where younsend the ajax?

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you already have jquery why no use it on everything, and I made a change the parameter in the ajax call

```
function showName(str) {

        if (str == "") {
            $("#playerInfo").html("Player information will be listed here.");
            return;
        }

        var n = "path/to/jboss" + str;
        $("#testURL").html(n);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: n,
            success: function (resp) {
                $("#playerInfo").html(resp);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#playerInfo").html("Error: " + e);
            }
        });
    }
```